# How to perform arithmetic operations with specific elements of a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to understand how to perform arithmetic operations on a dataframe in python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[2,38,7,5],'col2':[1,3,2,4]})

print (unsorted_df.sum())
```

This is what I'm getting (in terms of the output), but I want to have more control over which sum I am getting.

```
col1    52
col2    10
dtype: int64
```

Just wondering how I would add individual elements in the dataframe together.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's the desired output you are looking for?

Comment: For example, I want to be able to add/subtract/multiply/divide any two elements of the dataframe, and just get that integer as my output. Or do that same thing with columns (ex. - adding up all of the numbers in column 1 and getting an integer).

Comment: OK, can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54294886/edit) with **one** *specific* example, including input/output? This works better with SO than such a broad / arbitrary requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but still I will try to cover all possible scenarios,

Input:

```
df

   col1 col2
0   2   1
1   38  3
2   7   2
3   5   4
```

If you want the sum of columns,

```
df.sum(axis = 0)
```

Output:

```
col1    52
col2    10
dtype: int64
```

If you want the sum of rows,

```
df.sum(axis = 1) 

0     3
1    41
2     9
3     9
dtype: int64
```

If you want to add a list of numbers into a column,

```
num = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df['col1'] = df['col1'] + num
df
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0   3   1
1   40  3
2   10  2
3   9   4
```

If you want to add a list of numbers into a row,

```
num = [1, 2]
df.loc[0] = df.loc[0] + num
df
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0   3   3
1   38  3
2   7   2
3   5   4
```

If you want to add a single number to a column,
    df['col1'] = df['col1'] + 2
    df

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0   4   1
1   40  3
2   9   2
3   7   4
```

If you want to add a single number to a row,

```
df.loc[0] = df.loc[0] + 2
df
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0   4   3
1   38  3
2   7   2
3   5   4
```

If you want to add a number to any number(an element of row i and column j),

```
df.iloc[1,1] = df.iloc[1,1] + 5
df
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0   2   1
1   38  8
2   7   2
3   5   4
```